# Doxygen - unable to load isutils.dll

Tags: doxygen

I'm installing Doxygen on Windows 8.1 64 bit. At the end of installation, it throws up "unable to load isutils.dll" followed by an unable to set PATH error. I'm not bothered about the PATH error, I presume that is just a case of manually adding "C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin" to the PATH but what is the isutils.dll error about and how do I fix it?

## Edited to add this:

I don't know if this is related or not but when I run the Doxygen wizard after installation and click the Select... button for scan/store directory, the application permanently shows the busy icon and stops responding, I have to break out of it using Task Manager.

Comment: "dsutils was a typo", I've edited and fixed it. Anyway, it turned out to be an Doxygen issue which the developer has fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response on the Doxygen mailing list from Dimitri van Heesch, the developer of Doxygen. He said that this appeared to be a glitch in the installer script which he has fixed. I downloaded the new version and it installed with no issues.

Comment: Note the 1.8.10 version is the version that was fixed. See https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/files/ and more specific in this case https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/files/rel-1.8.10/)